# How to combine two box-whisker plots into one using gnuplot

Tags: graph, gnuplot

I have two box-whisker plots, one showing time, another memory usage. Please see below:

Box-Whisker plot showing time usage:
http://goo.gl/jhYBXr

Box-Whisker plot showing memory usage: 
http://goo.gl/0Wvamh

Is there anyway in gnuplot to combine these two into 1 graph? Ideally, I want two box-whisker plots per 'X' entry side-by-side. There will be two Y-axis - y1 showing time and y2 showing memory with different range.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The link for the memory plot is broken. If you update it, I can include the images.

Comment: Updated, link should work now. Forgot enable the 'view'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you haven't provided any example data, I used the data from gnuplot's `candlestick.dem` demo and assumed, you have the JDK numbers in the first column:

```
2.1 1 1.5 2   2.4 4   6.
2.2 2 1.5 3   3.5 4   5.5
3.0 3 4.5 5   5.5 6   6.5
3.1 4 3.7 4.5 5.0 5.5 6.1
4.0 5 3.1 3.5 4.2 5   6.1
5.0 6 1   4   5.0 6   9
6.0 7 4   4   4.8 6   6.1
7.0 8 4   5   5.1 6   6.1
```

The plotting is done like follows:

1. Plot an empty plot (with `linetype -3`, which doesn't draw anything) and use `xticlabels` to generate the custom xtics.
2. Plot the box-whiskers for the time usage shifted a bit to the left relative to the xtic
3. Plot the box-whiskers for the memory usage shifted a bit to the right relative to the xtic

For simplicity, here I use the same data for both time and memory, but you can of course use different data files and different `y2range` and `yrange`:

```
set boxwidth 0.2 absolute
set offset 0.5,0.5,0,0

set yrange[0:10]
set y2range[0:10]
set ytics nomirror
set y2tics
set ylabel 'time usage'
set y2label 'memory usage'
set xlabel 'JDKs'

set key left

plot 'data.txt' using 2:4:xticlabels(1) linetype -3 notitle,\
     '' using ($2-0.15):4:3:7:6 with candlesticks linetype 1 title 'Quartiles, time' whiskerbars,\
     '' using ($2-0.15):5:5:5:5 with candlesticks linetype -1 linewidth 2 notitle,\
     'data.txt' using ($2+0.15):4:3:7:6 with candlesticks linetype 2 axes x1y2 title 'Quartiles, memory' whiskerbars,\
     '' using ($2+0.15):5:5:5:5 with candlesticks linetype -1 linewidth 2 axes x1y2 notitle
```

This gives:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @Christoph! It worked. Just to clarify, 'lt' means 'line type', 't' means 'title', right?

Comment: @IshtiaqueHussain Yes, I'm used to use only the shorthands. I updated the example to use the more verbose options.