# gnuplot box-and-whisker clustered

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to plot a clustered box-and-whisker plots in gnuplot for two files and I want the outputs to share the same xtics. Instead, I get an xtic for each file. This is my script:

```
set term pdf color enhanced
#set output ".pdf"
set bar 2
set style fill empty
set ylabel "Link Speed (kbps)"
set xlabel "Rate (Mbps)"
set grid

plot "file1.txt" using ($1-0.05):5:4:10:9:xticlabels(2) with candlesticks title "video" whiskerbars lw 3 lt 2, \
     "" using ($1-0.05):7:7:7:7:xticlabels(2) with candlesticks lt 2 lw 5 notitle, \
     "" using ($1-0.05):3:xticlabels(2) with points lt 18 pt 7 ps 0.7 notitle, \
     "file2.txt" using ($1+0.05):5:4:10:9:xticlabels(2) with candlesticks title "tcp" whiskerbars lw 3 lt 3, \
     "" using ($1+0.05):7:7:7:7:xticlabels(2) with candlesticks lt 3 lw 5 notitle, \
     "" using ($1+0.05):3:xticlabels(2) with points lt 18 pt 7 ps 0.7 notitle
```

Comment: From what you write, this should be equivalent to the question [How to combine two box-whisker plots into one using gnuplot](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18707029/2604213), right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Thanks a whole lot for directing me there  @Christoph

Comment: It worked. Thanks once again @Christoph.