# Gnuplot mulitple yerrorbars with spacing

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to have multiple yerrorbars for each xtick. So far, I can have all my error bars but they are displayed one of top of the other. I would like to have them separated with some space, a bit like with histogram but without the histogram columns.

Data file is formatted like:

```
xtick avg min max avg2 min2 max2 avg3 min3 max3 ...
```

Gnuplot file:

```
set format y "%.0f"
set xtics nomirror rotate by -45  autojustify
set ytics nomirror
set logscale y
set key outside right center Left
set size 1, 1
set term png size 1000, 400
set output "gedf_bytasks.png"
set datafile sep ' '
set datafile missing '-'
set datafile commentschars '#'
plot for [i=2:14:3] 'file.dat' using 0:i:i+1:i+2:xticlabels(1) with yerrorbars title columnhead(i)
```

Output:
[Ouput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pn6rj.png)

From the output image, I'd like to have the blue and yellow error bars side by side. Any idea?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

It is always when you finally post a question that you find an answer ...

Using [How to combine two box-whisker plots into one using gnuplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18707029/how-to-combine-two-box-whisker-plots-into-one-using-gnuplot), I have:

```
plot 'file.dat' using ($1+0.2):2:14:xticlabels(1) linetype 3 notitle,\
    for [i=2:14:3] '' using ($1+i*0.20):i:i+1:i+2 with yerrorbars title columnhead(i)
```

which works like a charm.

Cheers